# Error while importing from OMF

Tags: importing, aaf, omf

Hello. I'm posting this question here because I have scoured the DUC unsuccessfully and hopefully you might be able to help me:

I'm trying to import session data from an OMF exported from Media Composer using Pro Tools 7.3.1 LE.

Other OMFs exported from this same Media Composer are totally fine and I can import them easily - no problem.

The one exported this morning, however, doesn't let me open or import from it. The exact error message I get is:

"Could not complete the Import Tracks command because an unexpected error happened while trying to find an audio media file's format."

Anyone have a similar thing happen to them?

Of course this had to happen on a time-sensitive TV project... Supposed to have the dialogue edit done before lunch.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Ryan,

MXF media in an AVID project can cause this sort of error with OMF's ... the simple solution is to use AAF - make sure if at all possible they use embedded media -assuming your workflow allows it.

Comment: Thanks Sonsey! We just tried AAF also - doesn't work. She exported just a plain WAV for me and it works.

Comment: Hey - I fixed it. I went next door and found that there was a weird audio-file that was being referenced to and not even in the track, but just because it was being referenced, it wasn't letting me open the AAF. Thanks for answering so quickly. I'm accepting your answer 'cause you were so fast!

Comment: Ahhh the joys of OMF/AAF Export! Oh well, it's better than when it first came out - only half the OMF's worked at all! :) We actually had only ONE editor who was allowed to do them because he was the only one who could make them work!